# How can i display my data better. I'm having problems

Tags: php, css

```
    $sql = "SELECT moduleCode, moduleTitle FROM TIMETABLE";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr><td>Module Code</td><td>Module Title</td></tr></br>";
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr><td>". $row["moduleCode"]. "</td><td>". $row["moduleTitle"]. "</td></tr></br>";
            echo "</table>";
        }
    } 
    else {
         echo "0 results";
    }
```

I am having a problem with the layout of the data once its displayed from the database. Currently, the first record will be displayed in a clear table format, then any other record after that is just 'bunched up'. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: put `echo "</table>";` out side of loop(`while`).

Comment: Why do use `<br />`?

Answer (score 2):

Just like you started your `<table>` before the loop, you need to close it after the loop, not inside it. Also, no HTML (like `<br>`) is allowed between the cells, so remove the `<br>`. Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT moduleCode, moduleTitle FROM TIMETABLE";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><td>Module Code</td><td>Module Title</td></tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>". $row["moduleCode"]. "</td><td>". $row["moduleTitle"]. "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} 
else {
     echo "0 results";
}
```